# CKSMSComposeRemoteViewController timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose

Tags: xcode, sms

Ok, so sendSMS worked fine before on ios7 and below.  However, on ios8 the sendSMS function just fails with the error in the title of the question.  I am getting a warning here (after trying to resolve by changing NSArray to NSString using other stack overflow questions):     Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSArray *' from 'NSString *' for controller.recipients = recipients;  It is returning a result of MessageComposeResultCancelled.

```
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
    [self sendSMS:@"Play me on PokerBuddies. 
    Download the app at: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app   /poker-buddies/id404168013?mt=8" 
    recipientList:[NSString stringWithFormat:phone, nil]];
} else {
    phone = @"[None]";
}


- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSString *)recipients{

MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){
    controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
    controller.recipients = recipients;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Send SMS");

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem like MessageComposeController timeout issue .
I solved it by doing this.

You have to create instance variable of MFMessageComposeViewController and when you are going to present message controller you have to check if instance object is already created then do it nil and initialize that object again.So this error "CKSMSComposeRemoteViewController timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose" will not come and controller open exactly.

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    if (messageComposer) {
        messageComposer = nil;
        messageComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
    }
    messageComposer.recipients = arrPhoneNumber;
    messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    messageComposer.body = @"Your text";
    isMessageComposeAppear = 1;
    [self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: use of undeclared identifier messageComposer is what I get.  Haven't declared that anywhere as of yet, and not sure how to.